# AngularJS/JavaScript creating a new object from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, object

I have a problem that I've been stuck on for awhile and am looking for some advice.

On my controller I have a Restangular call to my back-end to retrieve some data, which looks like this

**Angularjs controller** (using Restangular)

```
Pages.controller('PageContentController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Restangular', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Restangular) {

    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

    Restangular.one('pages', $scope.id).getList('content').then(function(response) {
        $scope.content = response;

        $scope.content = _.forEach($scope.content, function(content) {
            content[content.name] = content.content;
        });
        console.log($scope.content);
    });

}]);
```

Now when I log out `$scope.content` I get an array with three objects that look similar to this

```
Array[3]
    0: Object
        banner_heading: "Services",
        id: 1

    1: Object 
        banner_text: "some banner text",
        id: 2

    2: Object
        banner_img: "services.jpg",
        id: 3
```

There is a lot more to these objects, but i've simplified it for the question and these are the only properties that I want to get out of the objects.

The banner_heading, banner_text, and banner_img are all properties that were dynamically created in the controller above using the lodash forEach loop.

Now on to what I am trying to accomplish. I need to create one object from this array of objects that looks like this

```
{
    "banner_heading": {
        "data": "Services",
        "id": 1 
    },
    "banner_text": {
        "data": "some banner text",
        "id": 2 
    },
    "banner_img": {
        "data": "services.jpg",
        "id": 3 
    }
}
```

Basically in my view I need to be able to output the data like `{{ banner_heading }}` but I also need to be able to maintain the ids for updating the data with the server side.

I'm not sure how this can be done, I've been puzzling over it for a few hours and would great appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you add to the question the actual JSON for the object you want?

Comment: @lucuma I'm not sure what you mean, I gave an example of what I am trying to accomplish in my last code snippet, is it not in the correct format?

Comment: that isn't a code snippet it looks like some output form a debug tool.  Is this what you want `{ {'banner_heading': 'services', id:1}, {'banner_text': 'some banner text', id:2}, {'banner_img':'services.jpg', id:3}}` ?

Comment: Can you at least use standard javascript notations to define the object you want?

Comment: No your example looks like it is three different objects, I need them all in one object so that I don't have to use `ng-repeat`

Comment: Your edit doesn't have a valid js object, this is why your question is confusing to me.  Anyways, if you want to do {{banner_heading}} on your view that is simple enough actually and I'll tailor my answer for that.

Comment: @MitchGlenn The object you are expecting is invalid JavaScript object.

Comment: @lucuma I just changed it to proper JSON, sorry about that.

Comment: @lucuma I'm sorry for the confusion, I think you should be able to understand what I am looking for now.

Comment: @MitchGlenn Doing `{{ banner_heading }}` won't output data instead it will output something like `"data": "Services","id": 1`. You need to do `{{ banner_heading.data }}` to just retrieve value `"Services"`

Comment: Yes I would be very happy with that! I'm not sure how to get there from the array of three objects I am starting with.

Comment: @RahilWazir if that's the case we might as well just write a simple function to pull the data from the original array:  `{{ getWhatever('banner_heading')}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to propose a solution that doesn't require grouping or doing anything with the original array data:

Assuming we have this per the question:

```
 $scope.content = [{ banner_heading: "Services", id: 1}, {banner_text:'some text', id:2}, {banner_img:'service.jpg', id:3}];
```

We can write a function to pull what we need:

```
$scope.getData = function(n) {
   // question states lodash is being used
   var row = _.find($scope.content, function(item) {
       return n in item;
   });
   return row[n];
}

$scope.getId = function(n) {
  var row = _.find($scope.content, function(item) {
       return n in item;
   });
   return row.id;
}
```

And on the view:

```
{{ getData('banner_text') }}
```

Here is a demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/eHT42YQTaXWtmpbGwUZB?p=preview

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure why this is returning undefined for me.

Comment: Make sure the string you pass into getData is the extact name of the key.

Comment: Yes, I am...hmm confused..I want this to work, it's a great and simple solution

Comment: Awesome, got it working. But my only problem remaining is that I don't have a way to get the individual ids

Comment: I need to be able to get the id to be able to handle a PUT request to edit each piece of the data (banner_heading, banner_text, banner_img)

Comment: I added another function just to show you how, the _.find could be cleaned up into one for both but you now have the parts!

Comment: I don't understand how I can use that function to get the specific id of say banner_heading?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57589/discussion-between-lucuma-and-mitch-glenn).